# how to add + 1 of the last record to mysql c# winform

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

In general, I have a test. During the passage of which the user receives points. And when another user passes the same test, points are assigned to both the first user and the second

how to assign points to the last user?

my mysql query

```
MySqlCommand command =
    new MySqlCommand("update `journal` set `balls` = `balls` + 1", db.getConnection());
```

solving the problem

```
update journal set balls = balls + 1 where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: Why not find the specific record you want to update?

Comment: I need exactly the last entry

Comment: How does your `journal` table look like?

Comment: id
Name
balls 
ects

Comment: I succeeded in everything I used - update journal set balls = balls + 1 where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()

Answer (score 0):

You should get the last data first before you execute update query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).